# OSX App for free-hand annotation of PDF with Wacom Tablet

Tags: pdf, drawing

I'm used to annotating pdf documents with Preview simply by highlighting and adding text. I'm thinking about purchasing a Wacom tablet to add some free-hand annotation to my documents, but Preview does not support free-hand annotation.

I'm also not interested in any graphics apps as I found the learning curve too steep for such a simple task.

**What OSX app supports free-hand annotation of PDFs with a Wacom tablet?**

Comment: Incidentally, I found that an iPad or iPad mini + stylus to be much more useful than a Wacom tablet, particularly with iCloud or Dropbox sync to my other computers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like [Notability](http://www.gingerlabs.com) which was originally an iOS app and now has a Mac counterpart.

I don't have a Wacom tablet, but what I like about Notability is the standard sorts of annotation (text, highlights) but also free-form text and drawing by a pen.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious choice would be Adobe Reader XI (or Acrobat, of course).

Adobe Reader XI supports all types of annotations (except Redaction to be correct) without requiring Extended Rights (which were necessary for earlier Reader versions).

Comment: Does it support Wacom, as the OP requested, and run on OSX? Is there a link to it? Any personal experience you can share?

Comment: Running on OSX, I can guarantee. On the other hand, I don't have current experience with Wacom tablets. However, if you are in proximity of an Apple Store, it might be worthwhile to make a visit and test it out (I think Adobe Reader is part of the standard installation of Apple Store computers).

Comment: Thanks for the update, Max! Could you please integrate the facts with your answer (maybe together with a link to *Adobe Reader XI*, where the OP could take a look at the "full description")? Essential information shouldn't be left in the comments alone. After that, we should remove our comments to "cleanup". Thanks!